# reconstruction figure legend in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

after plotting a figure I get a figure legend as below:[image]

```
DataFrame1.plot(legend=False)
patch,labels=ax.get_legend_handels_labels()
DateFrame1.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

How can I delete the 'Temp' in (Temp,2005) ,let become just 2005?

the DataFrame1 has three keys:Month,Year,Temp.

Comment: This is a good question, but I think there must be some way to do this without changing df...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to update your legend with the years:

```
ax = df.plot()

years = [2005, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2012]
# you can get years from you dataframe (but without seeing the dataframe I can't say exactly how)
# legend also accepts a Series or numpy array
ax.legend(years, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you!You help me a lot on this project.and my English!:D

Answer (score 0):

ues unique method to get every different year:

```
DataFrame1.plot(legend=False)
patch,labels=ax.get_legend_handels_labels()
DateFrame1.legend(str(unique(DataFrame1['Year'].value)),loc='best')
plt.show()
```

so it's work correctly.