# python pandas groupby plot with sorted date as xtick

Tags: pandas, plot, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe df with the following format

```
date          value       team
12/8/2015       1.2         'A'
12/8/2015       1.3         'A'
12/7/2015       1.2         'A'
12/6/2015       1.3         'B'
12/6/2015       1.1         'B'
12/7/2015       1.3         'B'
...............................
```

What I want is a figure with two curves representing two groups, with date as x-value, the average value of the corresponding date as the y value. What bother me is the date format seems not correct, as python complains

"Could not convert 12/8/2015... to numeric"

```
for label, group in df.groupby('team']):
      group.plot(x=group['date'], y=group['date'].mean(),label=label)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert your date to a timestamp.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Then you can group and unstack to get your desired data:

```
>>> df.groupby(['date', 'team']).sum().unstack('team')
           value     
team         'A'  'B'
date                 
2015-12-06   NaN  2.4
2015-12-07   1.2  1.3
2015-12-08   2.5  NaN
```

Add `.plot()` and you should get your desired result.

Comment: A follow up question, after I use plot function, how to make legend only shows 'team' instead of both 'date' and 'team'

Comment: never mind, answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886019/reconstruction-figure-legend-in-pandas

Comment: I was going to suggest `df2 = df.groupby(['date', 'team']).sum().unstack('team')`, `df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()`